# how to switch between scenes from keyboard?

Tags: interface

Am I missing something ?

Blender has a menu entry for nearly every command but switching between scenes or layers seems unreachable and that's very inconvenient when doing editing with VSE.

Any solution ? Or this is a feature request ?

The second problem is that the workspace state isn't saved when switching between scenes so doing editing in one scene and animation on another is slow, I have to use the mouse and click two times at two differents locations for every switch... :-o

Comment: You're not missing anything.  There are a few things that Blender doesn't expose keyboard shortcuts for, or sometimes even ways to add your own shortcuts to the keymap.  This is one of those.

Comment: Sadly this is not yet possible in blender, however you could use a bit of coding and whatnot to make this possible in an add-on.

Comment: @Yohello1 Maybe I'll try sometime somehow... ^_^"